# how to echo array using foreach in echo

Tags: php, html, foreach, echo

I have an array `$category_slugs`

how to output this using `echo`?

I have an error in code bellow:

```
echo "<div class='transition ".foreach($category_slugs as $slug){echo $slug;echo ' ';}."' data-category='transition'> " ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
<div class="transition <?php foreach($category_slugs as $slug){echo $slug . ' ';} ?>" data-category="transition">
```

> The concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments.

from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

But this code not a string.

```
foreach($category_slugs as $slug){echo $slug;echo ' ';}
```

So you will get a error.

This manual may help you [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Sorry for my bad english, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use foreach inside a `echo`. To achieve what you are trying you can use `implode` function, it concatenates the values of an array on a string.

```
echo "<div class='transition " .implode(' ', $category_slugs). "' data-category='transition'> " ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `<div>` in a for loop, like so

```
<?php

$slug_string = "";

foreach($category_slugs as $slug){

$slug_string .= $slug_string." ";

}

echo "<div class='transition ".$slug_string."' data-category='transition'> ";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$category_slugs =array('a','b','c');
foreach($category_slugs as $slug){
echo "<div class='transition ".$slug.' '."' data-category='transition'></div> " ;
}
```

Comment: thanks . I need a div tag and multi class . your code is echo multi div tag